# what mean by the symbol ` or \` in this makefile statement : export SRVHOME=`readlink -f \`dirname $0\`/../`

Tags: linux, shell, makefile, command

```
export SRVHOME=`readlink -f \`dirname $0\`/../`
```

I know it exports a directory variable . but what means by the symbol "\`" or "`" surround the command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever you put between two ` characters is a command run on a fork of your shell.
In this case, the command itself contains another pair of ` characters - hence, they must be escaped, which is done here by prepending a `\` character.

An other example:

```
$ set -x
$ date -d @`echo \`date +%s\``
+++ date +%s
++ echo 1357377825
+ date -d @1357377825
Sat Jan  5 11:23:45 EET 2013
```

*Note*: `set -x` displays all steps of a command. Helpful for debugging.

In **bash** you can run several encapsulated commands with `$(command)` instead:

```
$ date -d @$(echo $(date +%s))
+++ date +%s
++ echo 1357378055
+ date -d @1357378055
Sat Jan  5 11:27:35 EET 2013
```

Comment: I have taken the liberty to rewrite the first sentences, which I found unclear. If you don't like the result, change it again.